# How to fetch data from table and compare it and display the result in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, compare

[image: This is user table]

[image: This is test table]

I want to fetch the data from the table. I have two tables one test and another one is user and I want to compare the skillneed with skill and display the job that matches skillneed and skill. How can I do it?

`public function post( Request $request)
{
    Test::create([
       'jobtitle'=>$request['jobtitle'],
       'company'=>$request['cname'],
       'jdesc'=>$request['jdesc'],
       'skillneed'=>$request['Skills'],
       'duration'=>$request['duration'],
       'qualification'=>$request['qualification'],
       'experiance'=>$request['experiance'],
      'location'=>$request['location'],
    ]);
}



    protected function create(array $data)
    {
       return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
            'age' => $data['age'],
            'location' => $data['location'],
            'resume' => $data['resume'],
            'skills' => $data['skills'],
            'course' => $data['course'],
            'college' => $data['college'],
            'role_id'=>$data['role_id'],

        ]);
    }`

Comment: Is `skills` in `users` table a comma separated string? same for `skillneed` in `tests` table?

Comment: No, it is not comma seperated. I am able to fetch both the data but I want to compare them and see if they are matching then I will list that job otherwise I will not.

Comment: @AnishAnsari you need to check multiple users with multiple Test in same time or is 1 user with multiple test or 1 to 1? Post your code, you have posted a create method doesn't help what you need to do.

Comment: i want to compare one user skill with many skillneed that is one user with multiple test. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Can you post the table structure and sample data? It will be way easier to provide an answer :)

Comment: What do you mean by "compare the skillneed with skill"?

Comment: @MihirBhende I have posted the structure

Comment: @NicoHaase Hi, I mean I want to compare the value of Skillneed in the table and skill values of the user table. so that if skill required is equal to skill then i can post display the job to user. I hope you got it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
$skill = Auth::user()->skills;
$res = DB::table('tests')->where('skillneed',$skill)->get();
return view('jobs.jobmatching',compact('res'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you  can use `collection helper contains`

`$testCollection->contains('skillneed', $user->skills)` returns boolean

find all tests

`$filtered = $testCollection->where('skillneed', $user->skills);` return filtered collection

Or with DB

`$skills = Test::where('skillneed', $user->skills)->get()`

Comment: Hi thanks a lot but I am very new to laravel. I am getting "undefined varibale user " do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need to fecth user first `$user = $request->user()` or `Auth:user()`, I suggest you to go through the docs so you understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I get what you told

Comment: @AnishAnsari please consider accepting the answer, if was helpful.